# Traveling from Tirana, Albania to Korce, Albania

Tags: public-transport, albania, tirana

What is the preferred method to travel from Tirana to Korce, Albania? I believe Korce was fairly difficult to get to due to road conditions in the early 2000's but don't know how conditions are in 2019.  Any advice? 
Looking for train/bus options. Or do you need to hire private drivers?

Comment: You're looking for transit options like buses and trains, right? Not recommendations for driving routes? Just clarifying because you mentioned road conditions, which could indicate you'd be open to driving the route yourself.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as primarly opinion based. We can't know which method of travel *you* prefer. If you want to check the road conditions, Google Street View has pretty good coverage in Albania, at least along the main roads, so you can check there yourself how the roads are now.

Comment: I’d prefer to keep this open so people who have actually traveled from Tirana to Korce can respond and give useful advice.